# How to stop a loop with a stop button in Tk with complex functions?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have this program run every 1 min forever. The problem is that after I press "Start" and the time starts, I cannot click the "Stop" button because the window freezes. Any help is welcome.
I don't know how can stop the code without exit.

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import pandas as pd
from scipy.io import loadmat
from threading import *


Height = 550
WIDTH = 800

asi = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(asi, height=Height, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()
backfround_image= tk.PhotoImage(file='water.png')
backfround_label = tk.Label(asi, image=backfround_image)

frame = tk.Frame(asi, bg="lightblue")
frame.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.1,relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8)
backfround_label.place(relwidth=1,relheight=1)

#bt.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.6,relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.1)
####################################################

path_field = tk.Entry(frame,bg="gray", width=30)
#path_field.grid(row=1, column=1)
path_field.place(relx=0.29,rely=0.05,relwidth=0.45)

def file_found(): # using for path from computer
    path_browse = fd.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select A file",
                                          filetype=(("Excel Workbook", "*.xlsx"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    path_field.delete(0, END)  # Remove any previous content
    path_field.insert(0, path_browse)  # Insert new content
    path_field.bind("<Return>", path_browse)

label=tk.Label(frame, text="Enter Data:", bg="#00bfff" ,width=20)
#label.grid(row=1, column=0,padx=5,pady=10)
label.place(relx=0.03,rely=0.05)


browse_file = Button(frame, text="Browse",command=file_found)
browse_file.place(relx=0.77,rely=0.04)
#browse_file.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=E)


####################################################

lHP=tk.Label(frame, text="Enter Hp:", bg="#00bfff",width=20)
#lHP.grid(row=2, column=0,padx=5,pady=10)
lHP.place(relx=0.03,rely=0.12)


entryHP= tk.Entry(frame, bg="gray",width=10)
entryHP.insert(END,'12')
entryHP.place(relx=0.29,rely=0.12)
#entryHP.grid(row=2, column=1)
####################################################

lNe=tk.Label(frame, text="Enter Ne:", bg="#00bfff",width=21)
#lTsim.grid(row=2, column=2,padx=5,pady=10)
lNe.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.12)

entryNe= tk.Entry(frame, bg="gray",width=10)
entryNe.insert(END,'12')
entryNe.place(relx=0.76,rely=0.12)
####################################################


lNNL=tk.Label(frame, text="Enter NNL:", bg="#00bfff",width=13)
lNNL.place(relx=0.03,rely=0.2)

entryNNL= tk.Entry(frame, bg="gray",width=9)
entryNNL.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.2)

lHNL=tk.Label(frame, text="Enter HNL:", bg="#00bfff",width=13)
lHNL.place(relx=0.32,rely=0.2)

entryHNL= tk.Entry(frame, bg="gray",width=9)
entryHNL.place(relx=0.48,rely=0.2)

lLNL=tk.Label(frame, text="Enter LNL:", bg="#00bfff",width=13)
#lTsim.grid(row=2, column=2,padx=5,pady=10)
lLNL.place(relx=0.6,rely=0.2)

entryLNL= tk.Entry(frame, bg="gray",width=9)
entryLNL.place(relx=0.77,rely=0.2)




####################################################
## create new frame   for low-tide

frame_L2 = tk.Frame(frame,bg="#b3ecff")
frame_L2.place(relx=0.03,rely=0.28,relwidth=0.36, relheight=0.05)
Lframe_L2= tk.Label(frame_L2, text="Weights for low tide",bg="#b3ecff")
Lframe_L2.pack()

frame_L = tk.Frame(frame, bg="#b3ecff")
frame_L.place(relx=0.03,rely=0.33,relwidth=0.36, relheight=0.38)



# create entry for weights low tide
Lug = tk.Label(frame_L, text="Enter Weight ug :", bg="#00bfff",width=20)
Lug.grid(row=4, column=0,padx=5,pady=10)

entryug= tk.Entry(frame_L, bg="gray",width=10)
entryug.insert(END,'5')
entryug.grid(row=4, column=1 )
#------------------------------
Ldug = tk.Label(frame_L, text="Enter Weight \u0394ug :", bg="#00bfff",width=20)
Ldug.grid(row=5, column=0,padx=5,pady=10)

entrydug= tk.Entry(frame_L, bg="gray",width=10)
entrydug.insert(END,'5')
entrydug.grid(row=5, column=1)
#------------------------------
Lup = tk.Label(frame_L, text="Enter Weight up :", bg="#00bfff",width=20)
Lup.grid(row=6, column=0,padx=5,pady=10)

entryup= tk.Entry(frame_L, bg="gray",width=10)
entryup.insert(END,'1000')
entryup.grid(row=6, column=1)
#------------------------------
Ldup = tk.Label(frame_L, text="Enter Weight \u0394up :", bg="#00bfff",width=20)
Ldup.grid(row=7, column=0,padx=5,pady=10)

entrydup= tk.Entry(frame_L, bg="gray",width=10)
entrydup.insert(END,'5')
entrydup.grid(row=7, column=1)

####################################################
## create new frame   for high tide

frame_L3 = tk.Frame(frame,bg="#b3ecff")
frame_L3.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.28,relwidth=0.36, relheight=0.05)
Lframe_L3= tk.Label(frame_L3, text="Weights for high tide",bg="#b3ecff")
Lframe_L3.pack()

frame_L1 = tk.Frame(frame, bg="#b3ecff")
frame_L1.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.33,relwidth=0.36, relheight=0.38)



# create entry for weights High tide
Hug = tk.Label(frame_L1, text="Enter Weight ug :", bg="#00bfff",width=21)
Hug.grid(row=4, column=0,padx=5,pady=10)

entryHug= tk.Entry(frame_L1, bg="gray",width=10)
entryHug.insert(END,'10')
entryHug.grid(row=4, column=1)
#------------------------------
Hdug = tk.Label(frame_L1, text="Enter Weight \u0394ug :", bg="#00bfff",width=21)
Hdug.grid(row=5, column=0,padx=5,pady=10)

entryHdug= tk.Entry(frame_L1, bg="gray",width=10)
entryHdug.insert(END,'5')
entryHdug.grid(row=5, column=1)
#------------------------------
Hup = tk.Label(frame_L1, text="Enter Weight up :", bg="#00bfff",width=21)
Hup.grid(row=6, column=0,padx=5,pady=10)

entryHup= tk.Entry(frame_L1, bg="gray",width=10)
entryHup.insert(END,'1000')
entryHup.grid(row=6, column=1)
#------------------------------
Hdup = tk.Label(frame_L1, text="Enter Weight \u0394up :", bg="#00bfff",width=21)
Hdup.grid(row=7, column=0,padx=5,pady=10)

entryHdup= tk.Entry(frame_L1, bg="gray",width=10)
entryHdup.insert(END,'10')
entryHdup.grid(row=7, column=1)




####################################################

#  connect to main code
def MPC1(path_field):
    global data
    import os
   # top=Toplevel()
    user_path = path_field
    if os.path.exists(user_path):
        #data = pd.read_excel(user_path)
        data=loadmat(user_path)
        #Label(top, text="File Found!").pack()
        print("File Found!")
    else:
        print("Input Directory does not exists.")
       # Label(top, text="Input Directory does not exists.").pack()
    return


def MainMPC():
    from Main_Code import Maincode
    global stop
    stop = 0
    str1 = path_field.get()
    str2 = int(entryHP.get())
    str3 = int(entryNe.get())
    str4 = int(entryug.get())
    str5 = int(entrydug.get())
    str6 = int(entryup.get())
    str7 = int(entrydup.get())
    str8 = int(entryHug.get())
    str9 = int(entryHdug.get())
    str10 = int(entryHup.get())
    str11 = int(entryHdup.get())
    str12 = int(entryNNL.get())
    str13 = int(entryHNL.get())
    str14 = int(entryLNL.get())

    MPC1(str1)
    t = Thread(target=Maincode(data,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7,str8,str9,str10,str11,
               str12,str13,str14))
    t.start()


def stop():
    # Assign global variable and set value to stop
    global stop
    stop = 1

def clear():
  asi.destroy()





bt_start = tk.Button(frame, text="Run", bg="#3492eb", fg="blue",width=8, command=MainMPC)
bt_start.place(relx=0.29,rely=0.75)

bt_stop = tk.Button(frame, text="Stop", bg="#3492eb", fg="blue",width=8,  command=stop)
bt_stop.place(relx=0.41,rely=0.75)


bt_clear = tk.Button(frame, text="Close", bg="#3492eb", fg="blue",width=8, command=clear)
bt_clear.place(relx=0.53,rely=0.75)
#bt_clear.grid(row=10, column=3, padx=0,pady=20)
#bt.grid(row=10, column=1, padx=0,pady=50)



asi.mainloop()
```

Also, when I run the code I can not click on others bottom. there are some other functions that I can not put them here.
Could you please help, how can solve this problem when I use the approach in a small program, it;s work but not for this program.

Comment: There is no "Start" button in your code — I assume you mean "Run". Regardless, threads don't really run concurrently in Python, so when you start one the rest of the code in the main thread is halted until the started thread does I/O, calls `time.sleep()`, or after a certain number of byte code instructions have been executed. The effect of this is that the GUI will freeze or hang because the event-processing it does is being interfered with. You need to modify `Maincode` to relinquished control periodically and stop blocking the main thread.

Comment: P.S. One issue related your code I noticed is that you have both  a global variable *and* a global function named `stop` which will never work — they must given distinct names because a global name can only assigned to one item at any given time. I suggest you call the non-function one `stop_flag` or something similar to that.

Comment: @martineau
Thank you for your help. How can modify the 'Maincode' to relinquish control periodically and stop blocking the main thread?

Comment: If there's a main processing loop in `Maincode`, you can put a call to `time.sleep()` somewhere in it to periodically give the main thread a chance to run. You will have experiment with different delay times so see how much is necessary.

Comment: @martineau In fact, I use the `time.sleep(60)` in `Maincode, but I don't know it's in correct place or not?

Comment: That's way too long of a delay. something less than a second should be adequate. It must happen multiple times, which is why I said put it in the main processing loop (assuming there is has one).

Comment: `target=Maincode(...)` is calling the function *right now*, in the main thread, thus blocking your GUI until the function returns.  This makes the use of a thread completely pointless.  You just want `target=Maincode`, with the parameters in a separate `args=` parameter.